# P5js [Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took 75ms

Tags: p5.js

I am getting this 'requestAnimationFrame' error with this code. I guess there's something with the for loop that causes the problem but I can't figure an alternative way of getting the same visual result. Any idea?

```
let zoff = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(0);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  scale(40);
  noStroke();
  fill(255);

  for (let a = 0; a < 7; a += 0.0012) {
    
    let x = cos(zoff) * 20 * sin(a);

    let y = cos(zoff+x/2) * 10 * cos(a);

    let e = cos(x) / sin(y) + zoff;

    circle(sin(e) * y, cos(e) * y, 0.091);
    
  }

  zoff += map(mouseX, 0, width, -0.03, +0.03);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an error, just a warning. It just means your frame is taking a relatively long time to draw. Since each frame you are looping 7 / 0.0012 = 5833 loops * 8 trig functions = 46664 trig calls per frame. If you are doing something like drawing frames to be exported and rendered as a video, that would be safe to ignore, but if this is for something real time, you'll have to figure out some optimizations.

Comment: Yes, but it is annoying...

Answer (score 0):

Well it doesn't give me the same, I just copied it into https://editor.p5js.org/ and works perfectly, maybe it's something with your html file. It also seems to have nice performance, so if copying it into a new sketch doesn't work try commenting different parts of the code or maybe using a different browser. It might just be a p5.js bug.